# Invalid procedure call or argument on call on a COM-Visible method with a COM-Visible object parameter

Tags: .net, types, vbscript, com-interop

***DISCLAIMER:*** Before posting this question I read the following ones and their answers:

- *[2791996](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791996) - C# COM objects with VB6/asp error*
- *[4793844](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793844) - Passing strongly typed arguments in .NET COM interop*

I wrote a wrapper of the .NET `Mail` Class and another one for `SmtpClient` to make them usable in ASP Classic and VB6.

Below the `SMTPSender` COM-visible class which wraps `SmtpClient` and its interface (Dual to keep early binding):

```
<Guid("f588b9e7-7107-4f3a-83a9-5e0e8f5297fd")>
<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)>
Public Class SMTPSender
    Implements ISMTPSender
    '
    Public Sub sendMail(ByVal mail As MailUtils.Mail) _
        Implements ISMTPSender.sendMail
        ' [...]
    End Sub

<Guid("cfe5e99b-c66a-4afb-8770-c0330994a823")>
<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)> _
Public Interface ISMTPSender
    '[...]
    Sub sendMail(ByVal mail As MailUtils.Mail)
    '[...]
End Interface
```

Below the Mail COM-visible object which wraps `MailMessage` and its interface (Dual too):

```
<Guid("d9252161-0731-4e6c-9964-66e4f56b97fa")>
<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)>
Public Class Mail
    Implements IMail
    ' [...]
End Class

<Guid("05a149ff-36e4-4905-9193-2fb8d31f5bd8")>
<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)>
Public Interface IMail
    ' [...]
End Interface
```

I cannot use ISmtpSender.sendMail in VBScript as well as in VB6 if I use non-typed variables. Below the block in which occurs the issue:

```
Dim smtpsender: Set smtpsender = CreateObject("Mailing.SMTPSender")
' [...] SMTP configuration...

Dim mail As mail: Set mail = CreateObject("Mailing.Mail") ' Typed variable
Dim mail2: Set mail2 = New MailUtils.mail                 ' Variant
' [...] mail and mail2 filling...

smtpsender.sendMail mail  ' Success
smtpsender.sendMail mail2 ' Fails "Invalid procedure call or argument"
```

I explicitely assigned a GUID for each class and interface, and prevented Interface autogeneration for each class (`ClassInterfaceType.None`). I still get this error message.

However, surrounding the argument with parenthesis (based on an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14074838/4375327) of the question [4793844](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793844)) removes the error:

```
smtpsender.sendMail (mail2)
```

I don't understand why, since `mail2` is passed by value (the value is a reference to the object content as well as in other languages IIRC).

The last solution isn't the cleaner way.

I cannot use typed variable since these COM-visible objects will be used in ASP **Classic VBScript pages**, which work **only with untyped variables**. What did I missed to make `SMTPSender` working?

Comment: You missed nothing. VBScript only knows VARIANT variables, so it has to convert everything to VARIANT internally. SendMail's argument is still a reference (even if you marked it as byval, it's a reference to an object). You have two options: pass your object as VARIANT (object in VB.NET) - ADO COM does that -, or use parens. For information, there's nothing wrong with using parens. Here is an example from Microsoft that uses arguments with parens: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/imapi/burning-a-disc (ChooseImageDefaults is defined the same way as your sendMail method)

Comment: @Simon Mourier, thank you. I don't understand why it works with parenthesis (which should  protect the value of the reference variable itself, not the pointed content). Is there some documentation about this point?